# Tricky improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to check convergence of $$\int_{-\infty}^{2}\frac{e^x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}\ dx \ ?$$
No convergent integral that could bound this one came to my mind, nor any which would fit asymptotic criterium. Any hint maybe?

Comment: There are two behaviours that could prevent integrability. Too fast growth at a singularity in $\mathbb{R}$ - the relevant points are $\pm 1$ - and too slow decay at infinity ($-\infty$ here). Look at each separately to conclude integrability.

Comment: As an aside, for $a>-1$, $$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}(x^2-1)^a~e^x~dx=2^a\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\cdot a!\cdot\text{BesselK}_{a+\frac12}(1).$$ This can be shown using the substitution $x=\cosh t$, and then employing the definition of the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). In this case, $a=-\dfrac13$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said there are 3 critical points: $-\infty$ and $\pm1$. Note $\pm1$ have same character. So we should observe 2 cases:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{-2}\frac{e^x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}\ dx < C_1
\int_{-\infty}^{-2}e^x\ dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{e^x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}\ dx < C_2
\int_{-2}^{-2}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}\ dx,
$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ some constants. We have proved convergence.